# How to store and access a sessionToken from AngularJS controllers?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an Angular authController that receives a `sessionToken` from the backend in case the authentication has been successful, and sets it as `$http.defaults` header.

It seems setting this header only affects the `$http` "instance" of the authCtrl, and not all usages of `$http` in other controllers. Correct?

How should I store and access this `sessionToken` for use in other controllers? The example I read was broadcasting and listening via

```
// in authCtrl:
$scope.$broadcast("sessionToken", data.sessionToken);

// in otherCtrl:
$scope.$on("sessionToken", function(sessionToken) { 
    $http.defaults.headers.common["X-Parse-Session-Token"] = sessionToken;
});
```

But it seems this does not work if the otherCtrl has not yet been initialized and is therefore not listening.

**Update**: some more code / context:

authCtrl:

```
angular.module("sportsStoreAdmin")
    .constant("authUrl" , "https://api.parse.com/1/login")
    .constant("ordersUrl" , "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Orders")
    .run(function ($http) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common["X-Parse-Application-Id"] = "XXXXX";
        $http.defaults.headers.common["X-Parse-REST-API-Key"] = "YYYYY";
    })
    .controller("authCtrl", function($scope, $http, $location, authUrl) {
        $scope.authenticate = function(user,pass) {
            $http.get(authUrl, {
                params: {
                    username: user,
                    password: pass
                }
            }).success(function (data) {
                $scope.$broadcast("sessionToken", data.sessionToken);
                $http.defaults.headers.common["X-Parse-Session-Token"] = data.sessionToken;
                console.log("authCtrl - set sessionToken " + data.sessionToken);
                $location.path("/main");
            }).error(function (response) {
                $scope.authenticationError = response.error || response;
            });
        }

 //...

        console.log("authCtrl initialized!");
    })
```

productCtrl:

```
angular.module("sportsStoreAdmin")
    .constant("productUrl", "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Products/")
    .run(function ($http) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common["X-Parse-Application-Id"] = "XXXXX";
        $http.defaults.headers.common["X-Parse-REST-API-Key"] = "YYYYY";
    })
    .controller("productCtrl", function ($scope, $resource, productUrl) {

        $scope.$on("sessionToken", function(sessionToken) {
            console.log("productCtrl - set sessionToken " + sessionToken);
            $http.defaults.headers.common["X-Parse-Session-Token"] = sessionToken;
        });

 // .....
 console.log("productCtrl initialized!");
```

(The whole example is from Apress book "[Pro AngularJS](http://www.apress.com/9781430264484?gtmf=s)", Chapter 8 - the examples in the book use Deployd, but the sourcecode download on the Apress site has this updated version, using Parse.)

Comment: i dont think so, `$http` should be a singleton and `$http.defaults.headers.common` should be applied to the only instance. any code you can show here?

Comment: Added more code/context.